# initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, string

```
class Song
  def initilaize(name,artist,duration)
    @name=name
    @artist=artist
    @duration=duration 
  end
end

song = Song.new("ruby","Bicylops " ,260)
puts song.artist
```

Comment: You're going to need to format this properly. This code is exceedingly unreadable.

Comment: You spelled `initialize` incorrectly.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO, formulating a question that clearly states what you are trying to do and what went wrong will greatly help others help you.

Comment: `song.artist` wouldn't work either. `artist` is instance variable of `Song`. To access it that way, you will either have to add in `attr_reader` list or make getter method `def artist; @artist; end`

Comment: the method name is not correct: initilaize => initialize

Answer (score 2):

Very simple.

You spelled `initialize` as `initilaize`.